# C# Outlook Plugin : How to get my own Office Communicator status

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am trying to write an outlook plugin in C#.

For a feature I want to know if my communicator status is away/available/Busy.
Based upon that I'll take various actions.

Please let me know the best way to doing this.

I am trying to use OfficeCommunicatorAPI, but not sure what to use.

PS. I am new to C# Development and MS API.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
It can be fetched from CommunicatorAPI .

```
       var a = new CommunicatorAPI.Messenger();
        if(a.MyStatus == MISTATUS.MISTATUS_ONLINE)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Online");
        }
        else if   (a.MyStatus == MISTATUS.MISTATUS_AWAY)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Away");
        }
```